# C# getting item from class

Tags: c#, list, class

I have a class called `rateTime`

```
class rateTime
{
   private List<string> t = new List<string>();
   private List<string> s = new List<string>();

   public rateTime(string[] time, string[] sender)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < time.Length; i++)
       {
           t.Add(time[i]);
           s.Add(sender[i]);
       }
    }

    ~rateTime() { }

    public List<string> Time
    {
       get { return t;}
       set { t = value; }
    }

    public List<string> Sender
    {
       get { return s; }
       set { s = value; }
    }
}
```

The DataSource of my combobox is set as follows:

```
rateTime rt = new rateTime(time, rateSender);
cb_rateTime.DataSource = rt.Time;
cb_rateTime.DisplayMember = "time";
```

In both lists I have 28 strings. I set items from List t as combobox items. And if I chose an item from the combobox with index, for example 10, I want know how can I get the string from list s with index 10.

Comment: This is a terrible question. You need to discuss what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve before you post a bunch of code that only says "i had class ratetime."

Comment: Appropriate, rebuking response by a user named "YourMother" ;)

Comment: Woah, I haven't seen a destructor used since my days of c++ ~...()

Answer (score 1):

try elementAt(index) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx 
or indexer - yourList[index]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood well, but:

```
var index = cb_rateTime.SelectedIndex;
var itemS = rt.Sender.elementAt(index);
```

or

```
var selected = cb_rateTime.SelectedText;
var itemS = rt.Sender[selected];
```

That should resolve.

Comment: This is how I understood it as well.

Comment: the problem i guess is that `rt` is created locally in a different method and is not available in the postback.

Answer (score 0):

Access it by index as in

```
MyRateTime.Sender[10]
```